# chainer build to test chainerx failing

Tags: chainer

Hello I'm having an issue where building chainer is failing on Windows 10. I have all the appropriate environment variables set as specified in the chainerx installation documentation. It seems to be failing on the chainerx_cuda build. Is there a specific version of CUDA or cudnn that I should be using? I'm currently running CUDA 10.0  and cudnn 7.6.3.30.

thanks

The error print out was too large to paste here. Please see link to text file below.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XL-ICp2D7ZgACAYtQcSYtABkNHObqDFU

Comment: It seems that the output you pasted does not contain reasons of the error . Could you share the full output?

Comment: Thanks I provided a link to file above. Stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to post that many lines... On line 912 I did find this error:

C:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0553ccb5\chainer\chainerx_cc\chainerx\routines\connection.cc(365): error C2280: 'chainerx::BackwardBuilder::BackwardBuilder(const chainerx::BackwardBuilder &)': attempting to reference a deleted function [C:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0553ccb5\chainer\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\chainerx\routines\chainerx_routines.vcxproj]

Comment: Thanks! The error is recognized as an issue and the fix is ongoing in the following pull-request: https://github.com/chainer/chainer/pull/8193

Comment: Great thank you! I'll keep an eye out for a merge to master.